# String containing function-line. How to echo in other file?

Tags: php, string, function, include

```
$str = "$obj = new class(); $obj->getSomeFunction();"
```

Is this possible? I am trying to develop a very dynamic platform to base my website off of.

Anyway to get this working? From a string by "echo $str;" it will make the object and run the function?

Comment: an included file acts as if the code was just copied and pasted in to position, i don't see that you would need to do the above

Comment: I suppose that instead of "very dynamic" you'll write "very buggy" platform. You don't need to do that terrible thing to have flexible program architecture

Comment: I suspect great frustration is forecast in your future. What? But why? Just learn PHP first.

Comment: ... and nothing personal, but I swear I will downvote each answer about `evIl()` function here ;-)

Comment: @zerkms - You do of course mean *[the thing that should not be](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)*?

Comment: @zerkms downvote me, I won't take it personal ;)

Comment: @Darhazer: hehe, I won't :-) Wrote that comment just to collect lulz and upvotes ;-P

Comment: @Darhazer: with your "help" another dynamic platform will be born... :-(

Comment: Oh man quick responses! - I know PHP to a certain extent (abstract classes, interfaces, api's etc.) feels like I've missed something here though. - The answers I've gotten so far as far as I see it is; "I don't know".

Comment: @Karl Morrison: they are not "don't know" but "you should implement it in another way". You've chosen the worst way to solve you issue though. Well, it is your wish to write terrible code ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are searching for is [eval](http://php.net/eval) but while it will do exactly what you are asking for, it's considered bad solution and can lead to messy code.

You can just include file that contains PHP code, or you can serialize meta data about the actions to be performed and then parse that data.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may be interested in [serializing objects in session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) as well as in [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) (a way to encapsulate set of operations in object(s))

Comment: Thank you! That's what it was! Thanks for the tip, will look into.

Comment: @Darhazer: me is a sad panda :-(

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing an object as a string, just create a new instance of your object. And once you've included a file.. All variables, objects, etc. exist in the file that includes that file.

Edit:

Instead of passing a class as a string, you can create classes dynamically:

```
<?php  
class cc {
    function __construct() {
        echo 'hi!';
    }
}

$type = 'cc';
$obj = new $type; // outputs "hi!"
?>
```

Alternatively you can use static classes:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public static function aStaticMethod() {
        echo 'hi!';
    }
}

Foo::aStaticMethod(); // outputs "hi!"

// or:

$classname = 'Foo';
$classname::aStaticMethod(); // outputs "hi!"
?>
```

Comment: Mr. Pallazzo I am very aware of how includes work!
It's very hard to explain what I'm trying to do (as what I'm trying to do has never been done before, hence to why I am asking yous). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Put it this way: I'm thinking VERY MUCH outside of the box atm.

Comment: It hasn't been done before because it creates security issues. I will edit my post with a working alternative..

Comment: Thing is, the include line in the parent php file is already defined. I wish for the function to be inserted wherever I wish it to be included within the parent page via a decisive parameter which will follow in the string. The object doesn't matter though. - As for security issues I white hack my own sites so I'm not worried at all.

Comment: Did you ever have a look at static functions? (Please read carefully when to use them and when NOT to use them.) http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Thing is this idea I have is so far from static as it comes. I wish for the string to be passed because I want to be able to control where in platform it will end up and in what order without having to actually write it in platform, hence why I'm asking if this is possible. I'm probably very bad at explaining what I want here, I apologize for that!

Comment: No.. that is not possible in a secure application.

Comment: I found it: eval()
Thank you for your dedication mate though! Have a good one!

Comment: `eval()` can make your application very very insecure!!

Answer (score 1):

In PHP included files are executed when you call [`include()`](http://php.net/include) or [`require()`](http://php.net/require). They follow [variable scope rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and even allow you to return results as if the include was a function like so:

**dynamicPlatform.php**

```
<?php
$object = include('createObjAndDoStuff.php');
?>
```

**createObjAndDoStuff.php**

```
<?php
$obj = new class();
$obj->getSomeFunction();

return $obj;
?>
```

As @zerkms has pointed out, you probably should be using [factories](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php).

```
class Factory {
    public static function someclass() {
        include_once('./classes/someclass.php'); //Although some discourage the use of *_once() functions
        $obj = new someclass();
        $obj->getSomeFunction();

        return $obj;
    }
}

//And to get a new class instance
$object = Singleton::someclass();
```

Or pseudo-singletons with factories:

```
class SingletonFactory {
    private static $someclass;

    public static function someclass() {
        if(!self::$someclass) {
            include('./classes/someclass.php');

            self::$someclass = new someclass();
            self::$someclass->getSomeFunction();
        }

        return self::$someclass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a rule that dynamic platforms don't use function or class-based factories, instead of included files? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Are you sure you didn't mean eval strings of code parsed from an ini file? (In all seriousness, yes I should be encouraging factories, so I'll link them for you. Thanks for the suggestion).

Comment: As for patterns I'm sorry but I also know patterns factory, singleton, prototype, builder etc.etc. Not what I'm looking for though! (Thank you for your dedication though!)
Anyone else know?

Answer (score 1):

I am in the process of writing my own mvc framework(as an learning project), and needed to dynamically create objects and call a method. I ended up using the reflection api in order to create a new instance of the object and then call the method. in this case i ended up passing an associative array that had two key/value pairs, the class name, and the method I wanted to call. I hope this helps.

$class = $command['class'];
        $method = $command['method'];

```
    try{
        $reflectorClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
        $reflectedInstance = $reflectorClass->newInstance($matches);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        exceptionHandler::catchException($e);
    }


    try {
        $reflectorMethod = new ReflectionMethod($reflectedInstance, $method);
        $reflectorMethod->invoke($reflectedInstance);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        exceptionHandler::catchException($e);
    }
```

Comment: You could use:
if (class_exists($command['class'])) {
   $class = new $command['class'];
   if (is_callable(array($class, $command['method'])) {
     $class->{$command['method']}() // or call_user_func if needed, for example for passing arguments
   }
}

No need for reflection here

Comment: I actually started by using those as well, but after just doing some reading and looking at other frameworks, reflection seemed appropriate as well. the reflection methods throw exceptions for me while class_exists just returns true or false. i've read that also reflection api is faster for these types of things rather than call_user_func for example.